# Boost.Python installation failing with bjam errors

Tags: python, boost, boost-python, bjam

I have been struggling to get Boost.Python running .

i am following the steps mentioned in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/python/doc/building.html . I followed section 3.1 step 2 . Bjam driver is giving my headaches . So as mentioned in the document i follow the steps outlined in Section 5 of http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-simplified-build-from-source .

Attempt at Section 5.2 gives me the following errors :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_50>.\bootstrap

Building Boost.Build engine

The system cannot find the path specified.

'.\build.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file.


Failed to build Boost.Build engine.

Please consult bootstrap.log for furter diagnostics.


You can try to obtain a prebuilt binary from


   http://sf.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=7586&package_id=7294
```

1

So since this attempt failed i tried adopting the steps outlined in 5.3 . I downloaded a jam zip file . and then built a jam.exe executable and then added the bjam exe to the PATH environment variable . So now attempting to do this

bjam --build-dir=build-directory toolset=toolset-name --build-type=complete stage

i.e

C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_50>bjam --build-dir="C:\build-boost" toolse
t=msvc --build-type=complete stage

fails with the following error ....

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_50>bjam --build-dir="C:\build-boost" toolse
    t=msvc --build-type=complete stage

    Unable to load Boost.Build: could not find build system.
    ---------------------------------------------------------
    C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_50\boost-build.jam attempted to load the bu
    ild system by invoking

       'boost-build tools/build/v2 ;'

    but we were unable to find "bootstrap.jam" in the specified directory
    or in BOOST_BUILD_PATH (searching C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_50\tools/
    build/v2).

Please consult the documentation at 'http://www.boost.org'.

C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_50>
```

Now the directory tools/build/v2 does not exist in my boost home directory .. SO i re-downloaded the boost bundle and repeated all steps. still no success  . now i dont know what to do ..

I want to get the examples given under the boost installation at  libs/python/example/quickstart/ up and running .

Can someone please help with the installation ??

EDIT ::

As i see it the boost-build.jam file contains the following entry

BOOST_BUILD ?= tools/build/v2 ;

But i dont have this tools directory ?? Has the boost directory structure changed . ? Should i expect a "tools" directory with my Boost installation ? i cant find the file " bootstrap.jam" either ?

Comment: Looks like you installed the pre-built boost libraries from boostpro. You don't need to build anything, just select the proper `Boost.Python` library under components at the installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i figured out the problem . I downloaded the boost config files from BoostPro instead of Boost.org . Well since i was a newbie i never realised it till it hit me hard . I was looking up at the Official boost documentation at Boost.org and obviously there were some discrepancies . So good to go now :-)

Comment: Can you explain how you fixed this issue?

Comment: @maheshakya i  had downloaded the incorect Boost package . Instead of downloading from Boost.org i downloaded BoostPro . They require slightly different environments . Be careful what you download and follow closely instructions for that version of Boost .